# Add an image or icon to primefaces tab header

Tags: image, header, tabs, icons, primefaces

im trying to use an image /icon on a tab header instead of text title(or may using both of them), i was testing using titleStyleClass seting an image background but doesnt work

my primefaces tab:

```
 <p:tab titleStyleClass="tCliente" title="Vehiculo">
```

My css style

```
 .tCliente 

 {     
   background-image: url(../images/logo_tropidatos.gif);
 }
```

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On PrimeFaces 3.0 and newer you can add a facet to override title on tabs:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:tab>
        <!-- overrides title on tab-->
        <f:facet name="title">
               <h:outputText value="tab title"/>
               <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/icon.png"/>
            </f:facet>

        <h:panelGrid>
            <!-- tab content -->
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>    
</p:tabView>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not working for me. My xmlns is xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui". What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any way to remove default right arrow (>) icon from `p:tab`?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

You should put:

`background-image: url("../images/logo_tropidatos.gif") !important;`

but after that i have a problem: the image repeat into the header.
I tried to solve adding `background-repeat:no-repeat;`  but is the same... can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
background-image: url("../images/logo_tropidatos.gif") !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
```

Comment: This is not a solution