# Primefaces TabPanel with Images

Tags: layout, jsf-2, primefaces, tabs

I read TabView example (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml) and made some code that work.  The image below is what I did.

My actual xhtml has the excerpt below that produces the result for the first image below.

```
<p:tabView orientation="left">
<p:tab title="Customer">
<p:graphicImage id="iconPerson"value="/resources/img/icon_person-128.png" />
```

[image: This is what I have]

But I would like to have a slight different layout, shown on the picture below.
[image]

EDIT:
I added the suggestion of facets, but it is not working as expected.  Maybe because this was a solution for PF3 and I am using 5.  But here is the result of my facet approach.

```
<p:tab id="customerTab" rendered="true" >
<f:facet name="Customer">
    <h:outputText value="Customer" title="Customer" rendered="true"/>
    <p:graphicImage id="iconPerson" value="/resources/img/icons/128/icon_person-128.png" height="64" width="64" />
</f:facet>
```

And here is the rendered result
[image]
How to do it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977591/add-an-image-or-icon-to-primefaces-tab-header

Comment: You didn't exactly follow the answer in the duplicate. You changed the name of the title facet to a non-existing name "Customer".

Comment: My bad.   It works.  I had only to f:facet name="title"